# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL in Tomee

Tags: netbeans, apache-tomee

I am trying to run my JSF project using Apache tomee-1.7.1-plume, JSF 2.1 in netbeans 8.0.2 but its not running with the following error. I don't know what is the problem> thanks in advance for help.

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FWindows%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext7091578542594637291.xml&path=/test
C:\Users\Windows\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 42 seconds)
```

Comment: How is this according to you jsf related? Why not netbeans? And did your read this: _"See the server log for details."_

Comment: if it is related to netbeans then what can be the possible solution and i have see the server log there is also the same error.

Comment: This is like asking a bicycle mechanic what is wrong with your stereo set without showing him. Corrected the tags for you